# Connecting R studio to IBM Netezza database using ODBC connection

Tags: r, rstudio, driver, netezza, rodbc

I need to connect to Netezza DB through R studio. I checked some pages already, the answers weren't clear. I don't know much about ODBC drivers and stuffs.

I have this folder that has bunch of dll and .jar files.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM Netezza ODBC Driver\jre.

Do i have to download any drivers and are there any specific R packages to install for this.

Comment: you can use `RODBC` and have your credentials stored in an `.odbc.ini` file

Comment: Thanks. What about the NZ drivers? Should i do anything for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this with RODBC package.

First, make sure ODBC connection is set up in ODBC Data source Administrator(Windows system).

Install RODBC package in R studio.
    library(RODBC)
    myconn <-odbcConnect("ODBC_connection_name", uid="user", pwd="pass")
    q_df <- sqlQuery(myconn,"select * from table", believeNRows=FALSE)

By default only 256 rows is imported. Set believeNRows=FALSE will import all the rows

Comment: Any chance this is possible on OSX?

Comment: In order to use ODBC on a Mac you'll need 2 things, an ODBC client and a driver. There are 2 popular clients, iODBC and unixODBC, either should work well. I have not yet found an ODBC driver for Netezza that will work on a Mac. The IBM website lists one, but I don't think its publicly available. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/c_datacon_configuring_odbc_unix_linux.html